# How can I listen for events before a service worker terminates in web workers?

Tags: web, service-worker, web-worker

Events equivalent to 'beforeunload' in web service workers

I was hoping to listen to events happen when the service worker is about to terminate or browsers begin to be closed by users. Therefore, I can do some last-minute cleanups (e.g. persist logs). Is this possible to do in service workers?